# Angular 2 Rollup Tree Shaking unexpected token in RxJS lib

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, rxjs, rollupjs

When I use Rollup from [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) I get an error when trying to execute rollup config js file:

```
 Unexpected token
    node_modules/rxjs/util/isArrayLike.js (2:78)
    1: "use strict";
    2: var isArrayLike_1 = function (x) { return x && typeof x.length === 'number'; });
                                                                                     ^
3: //# sourceMappingURL=isArrayLike.js.map
```

When I look into `isArrayLike.js` file in `rxjs` repo, I can see that file contains the following code:

`exports.isArrayLike = (function (x) { return x && typeof x.length === 'number'; });`

Looks like on tree shaking step rollup removes one of the brackets `this one -->(function (x)` and tree shaking fails.

If I manually remove last parenthesis in `rxjs/isArrayLike.js` file, rollup works fine.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

`"rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^7.0.0"
 "rxjs": "^5.2.0"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update Feb 22, 2017

As Toby mentioned, there seems to be some breaking changes in the recent package updates.  I'm not sure which package is causing the issue yet.

The current versions listed below works without issues. When I update to the the latest version, I get the same error that you do:

[image]

```
"@angular/common": "2.4.7",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.7",
"@angular/core": "2.4.7",
"@angular/forms": "2.4.7",
"@angular/http": "2.4.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.7",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.7",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.4.7",

"rxjs": "5.1.0",
"zone.js": "0.7.6"

"gulp-typescript": "3.1.4",
"systemjs": "0.20.7",
"typescript": "2.1.6",
```

### General Solution

1. Use NGC to compile the source (es5 target, and es6 module). This creates the factories in the `src` folder, and the metadata, and `.d.ts` files in the `dist` folder.

   Next create the required metadata and .d.ts files, by setting the following options in tsconfig-aot.json:

   ```
   "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "module": "es6",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "declaration": true,
        ...
    },
   "angularCompilerOptions": {
       "genDir": "",
       "skipMetadataEmit" : false
    }
   ```
2. Re-compile the `src` folder using `tsc`; inline the HTML using a plugin. I used `gulp-inline-ng2-template`:

   ```
      gulp.task('compile:es6', function () {
          return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.ts'])
            .pipe(inlineNg2Template({ base: '/src' }))
            .pipe(tsc({
                "target": "es5",
                "module": "es6",
                "moduleResolution": "node",
                "experimentalDecorators": true,
                "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
                "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
       }))
   ```
3. Copy the HTML files from the `src` folder to the `dist` folder. This part is necessary because NGC was compiled before the HTML templates was inlined.  As a result, the metadata still thinks your component is using templateURLs.  Hopefully, the community will come up with a good inline-html plugin, so that this step won't be necessary anymore.
4. Use rollup to shake the tree and create the bundles:

   ```
   gulp.task('rollup:module', function() {
     return rollup.rollup({
       entry: pkg.main,
       onwarn: function (warning) {
         // Skip certain warnings

         // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
         if (warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') { return; }
         // intercepts in some rollup versions
         if ( warning.message.indexOf("The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'") > -1 ) { return; }

         if ( warning.message.indexOf("treating it as an external dependency") > -1 ) { return; }

         if (warning.message.indexOf("No name was provided for external module") > -1) { return; }

         // console.warn everything else
          console.warn(warning.message);
       }

    }).then( function ( bundle ) {
       bundle.write({
          dest: `dist/${pkg.name}.bundle.umd.js`,
          format: 'umd',
          exports: 'named',
          moduleName: pkg.name,
          globals: {
          }
        });
        bundle.write({
           dest: `dist/${pkg.name}.bundle.cjs.js`,
           format: 'cjs',
           exports: 'named',
           moduleName: pkg.name,
           globals: {
           }
        });
        bundle.write({
           dest: `dist/${pkg.name}.bundle.amd.js`,
           format: 'amd',
           exports: 'named',
           moduleName: pkg.name,
           globals: {
           }
           });    
          });
       });
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/src'));
   });
   ```

When you publish your package (i.e. to npm), make sure that you include the js, .d.ts, and .metadata.js files in the same `dist\src` folder, and ensure that you have an index.js file for your main package entry point.

The bundles allow your users to load your package using any dynamic module loader; the js, .d.ts., and metadata.js files are required to make your package AOT-compliant - meaning others can install your library and also create AOT static bundles.

Hope this helps,
Cheers!

[Demo Starter Application (AOT Bundling)](https://github.com/pixelbits-mk/ng2-starter-app)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in rollup or the commonjs plugin. I haven't found, yet, the versions with which it works.

Here are links to the issues (github):

Rollup: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1310

commonjs plugin: https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs/issues/168

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error with 2.4.8 but after some tinkering with my rollup.config.js I got it to work.

Check out my package.json here and the rollup.config.js:

https://github.com/steveblue/angular2-rollup